# Locating and copying millions of images in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, image, photo2shape

I have image data collected across the US and Canada from 2016 and 2017.  I need to find all images that are within 5 meters of each other in order to compare changes in landscape over the year.  Eg, an image on I-80 East taken in 2016 and a similar image within 5 meters taken in 2017.  Once the images are found I need to copy them into separate folders for further analysis.

All the images are geolocated and there are approximately 20 million to go through.

I am considering using photo2shape to get the location then using a 5 meter buffer to find the images however processing time would be huge considering it takes about 10 minutes to do 100,000 images.  There is also the problem of copying the selected images to another folder which may be the hardest part.  I don't think the output file from photo2shape gives you the ability to copy the images with out opening them in qgis.

Has anybody done anything like this in QGIS?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Python.

Comment: PostGIS raster?

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to rent some server cycles.